# Помогите с задачей на периодичность, не получается

Tags: python

Профессор получил послание, оно представляет собой непрерывную последовательность из сигналов нескольких типов, каждый из этих типов обозначаем буквой лат. алфавита. Он считает, что доказательством искусственности происхождения сигнала служит его периодичность. При этом период должен быть строго равен "константе" - числу P. Такую последовательность назовём P - периодичной.

Некоторые сигналы были утеряны. Их заменили на знак вопроса. Теперь требуется выяснить, можно ли заменить утерянные сигналы на буквы так, чтобы последовательность стала P - периодичной. Для чистоты эксперимента, полученная последовательность была размещена среди себе подобных.
Формат входных данных:

В первой строке содержится два числа через пробел: N - общее количество строк, которые вам нужно проверить на P-периодичность и число P - константа ( 1≤ P≤5∗10^3)

Далее содержится N непустых строк, состоящих из малых букв латиницы и знаков вопроса. 1≤ N≤5∗10^4, суммарная длина всех строк не превосходит 2*10^5

Формат выходных данных:

Вывести N строк, в каждой из которых вывести либо "YES", если соответствующую строку можно сделать P-периодичной путем замены всех знаков вопроса на некоторые буквы и "NO" в противном случае. Считать последовательность P- периодичной, если для любых двух символов, расстояние между которыми кратно P верно, что они совпадают.

Написать программу

входные данные

```
8 4 
abacabaca
abracadabra
aa?aaa?aaaaaaaaaa
q
???????
q?er?w?
q?erw??
q?er?wer?werw?er
```

выходные данные

```
YES
NO
YES
YES
YES
YES
NO
NO
```

Пытался решить как то так, не могу разобраться с последней комбинацией

```
def func(word):

    a=word[:m]

    b=word[m:m+m]
    c,d='',''
    for j in zip(b,a):
        if  j[0]=='?': c+=j[1]
    else: c+=j[0]
    f j[1]=='?': d+=j[0]
    else: d+=j[1]
    print ('YES' if d in c else 'NO' )

    n,m=map(int,input().split())
    for i in range (n): func(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот такое решение не подойдет?

```
def check(word, period):
    # выровнять строку до размера, кратного периоду и заполнить остаток ?
    aligned_length = len(word) + (period - len(word) % period) if (len(word) % period) else 0
    aligned_word = word.ljust(aligned_length, '?')

    # сравнить части строки размером с период с первой частью строки размером с период, игнорируя ?
    for index in range(1, aligned_length // period):
        for pos in range(period):
            # сравнить буквы из двух частей стоки, если обе из них отличны от ? и в случае несовпадения - выйти
            if aligned_word[index * period + pos] != '?' and aligned_word[pos] != '?' and aligned_word[index * period + pos] != aligned_word[pos]:
                return False

    return True


words = ["abacabaca", "abracadabra", "aa?aaa?aaaaaaaaaa", "q", "???????", "q?er?w?", "q?erw??", "q?er?wer?werw?e"]

for word in words:
    print(word, 'YES' if check(word, 4) is True else 'NO')
```

Вот так функция покороче выглядит (убран лишний цикл, но вместо этого позиция каждой буквы через модуль считается):

```
def check(word, period):
    # выровнять строку до размера, кратного периоду и заполнить остаток ?
    aligned_length = len(word) + (period - len(word) % period) if (len(word) % period) else 0
    aligned_word = word.ljust(aligned_length, '?')

    # сравнить части строки размером с период с первой частью строки размером с период, игнорируя ?
    for pos in range(period, aligned_length):
        # сравнить буквы из двух частей стоки, если обе из них отличны от ? и в случае несовпадения - выйти
        if aligned_word[pos] != '?' and aligned_word[pos % period] != '?' and aligned_word[pos] != aligned_word[pos % period]:
            return False

    return True
```

Если смириться с увеличением строки, размер которой кратен периоду на размер периода, то первую строчку можно упростить

```
aligned_length = len(word) + (period - len(word) % period)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение с чтением из файла

```
#читаем первую строку
fin = open("text.txt", encoding="utf8")
n, p = map(int, fin.readline().split())
#создаем список из оставшихся строк
lst = []
for line in fin:
    lst.append(line.strip())
print(lst)
#если период меньше длинны то ДА
for line in lst:
    if len(line) <= p:
        print("YES")
        continue
#если нет, то в temp сохраняем буквы из первого периода первой сроки
    else:
        triger = 0
        temp = list(line[:p])
        for i in range(len(line)):
            #print(line[i], line[i%p])
# если буквы не равны вопросам и не равны между собой, то НЕТ
            if line[i] != temp[i%p] and line[i] != "?" and temp[i%p] != "?":
                print("NO")
                triger = 1
                break
# если в первом периоде первой строки были вопросы, то заменим их на первые попавшиеся буквы
            elif temp[i%p] == "?"  and line[i] != "?":
                temp[i%p] = line[i]
#проверяем чему равно t, если 0, то цикл дошел до конца печатаем ДА
            if triger == 0:
                print("YES")
```

Вывод:

```
YES
NO
YES
YES
YES
YES
NO
NO
```